# How to protect the copyright of the thesis draft?

Tags: thesis, copyright

I just finished the draft of my thesis and want someone else to do a proofreading on it because I am not a native speaker of English. I wonder if any things I shall do to protect the copyright of the draft before I pass it to others?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you want to protect? Because it might be that it's not solved by copyrights.

Answer (score 3):

If you live in the US or any other country that observes the rules of the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), your work is *automatically* protected by copyright as soon as it is saved to a fixed medium (which may be your hard drive, a printout, or scribbles in a notebook).

So if your work is written down, it's already protected with respect to *copyright*.

There may be other things about the draft that you wish to protect - for example, you may wish to ask the proofreader not to speak about your ideas with anyone else - but that is not a copyright issue.

Comment: It's usually *proving* that you hold the copyright to something which is the issue...

Comment: Could you please talk about last paragraph of your answer a little more? May be in form of a comment if you find it irrelevant to edit your answer to the original question. Thank you.